# Allow using the Elections mechanism to vote on Community decisions (direct democracy)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, election

Right now StackExchange has an excellent election mechanism which allows for a fair and transparent voting on Moderation candidacies. However there is no such mechanism for voting on site matters (e.g. "Should we allow questions about Tesla's software on SuperUser?"), so at most we can arrange a vote through a [Meta post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/poll-on-mass-editing-flooding-re-tagging-impacts-of-older-posts).

Is it possible for the Admins to extend the voting functionality to allow for decisions on matters beyond elections? Obviously polls could only be created by Mods and there should be a limit on how many votes can be held per year

Comment: What is wrong with voting on meta posts?

Comment: @PatrickHofman they get a lot less attention, which often makes it hard to come to a certain conclusion. They're more informal and very much non-binding.

Comment: And how do we decide on which matter to bring up for a referendum? With a meta post and voting on that post maybe?

Comment: @rene the mods can decide in whatever way they please

Comment: in which case, what if the mods decide not to allow any questions at all?

Comment: But then we first have to vote on the moderators not being just janitors because that is currently not how it works.

Comment: Meta posts can be "featured"  by the site mods, if you want more visibility on referendum posts.  Featured posts appear in the right-hand sidebar on every page on the main site.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking at a few things where meta could help better establish *consensus*, such as requests to remove or alter tags. I'd love it if tag requests could create a 'yes/no' poll which was made visible on the main site to users invested in those particular tags.

This has a few benefits:

- People that actually care would get more of an opportunity to weigh in
- You don't have to apply [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) to every such request in order to get it visibility
- These requests can linger for *years* sometimes. Establishing a cut-off point where the system understands *this goes in a queue if the answer is yes* would really help.

This works well for tags, where there's a pretty clear 'do or not do' scope. It *doesn't* work so well for discussions that result in multiple yet equally-valid opinions. While the idea of a single-transferrable vote seems like it might fit this problem, when all but one option seems terrible to you, that breaks down.

The other thing is we can't even begin to promise people that votes would always be binding. Communities with the best intentions can often favor ideas that would be exceptionally *bad* for them in the long run. It's the job of the moderators and the community team to help lead and steer folks in the right direction when decisions start to look scary.

It would feel very awkward to me to implement something that's not really any more consistent than what we currently have especially given the amount of time this would ask of people.

**At the same time, I agree with many of your points.** It's difficult to figure out what the community ultimately decided based on a series of meta discussions unless you have a thorough knowledge of the status quo.

I firmly believe that we could alter the behavior of things tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) *just* a little to make the experience better for everyone. I don't have any real concrete ideas yet, but I think the purpose of each tag is different enough that the idea is worth considering.

I'm open to ideas, but for the reasons I gave above, I'm going to decline this one.

Comment: Thank you for posting an "official" opinion! Here's my counter-proposal: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291779/show-featured-meta-post-on-the-main-site-for-logged-in-high-rep-users